# Beginner problem. How i can display all images from a product? Django + Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, e-commerce

I'm a beginner and i need a little help.
I want to display all images from a product and i can't find the right way.

the code is below:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   short_description = models.CharField(
    max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Enter a brief description of the product")
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
   digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
   default_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)


 def __str__(self):
    return self.name

 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('product-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

 @property
def imageURL(self):
    try:
        url = self.default_image.url
    except:
        url = ''
    return url


 def image_tag(self):
    return mark_safe('<img src="{}" height="50"/>'.format(self.default_image.url))

image_tag.short_description = 'Image'




  class ProductImage(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(
    Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, related_name='images')
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name
```

this is the view:

```
class ProductDetail(DetailView):
model = Product
```

URL:

```
path('product/<int:pk>', views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
```

and template product_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'store/home.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
    <!--<img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt=""> -->

    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

The comment is returning only the default image.
The indentation is correct in my VS Code but here is pretty hard to write it.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can create different fields for each image. For example default_image2, imageURL2 etc. Each field holds one image. Or you can create new images model and add it as a ForeignKey

Comment: @KyokoSasagava there is already a related image model as shown in the shared `models.py` snippet. Which makes it straightforward to do a reverse-relationship lookup; I've posted an answer.

Comment: @DJRamones he wants to add multiple images to single product so the ProductImage model needs image1, image2, image3 fields.

Comment: @DJRamones using for will show all the images in the database. You need to use ArrayField to use for loop for images from single product

Comment: @KyokoSasagava your sugestion i will apply last one. i had that in my mind but i want it done with a FK as i have it now. thank's for answer

Comment: @KyokoSasagava that's incorrect. Yes I'm using `for`, but I'm using the `FOO_set` reverse relationship lookup, so it should filter the ProductImage objects to only those related to a single product. It should not show all images in the database. Using `ArrayField` is an unnecessarily complicated solution, when this is something that the native `ForeignKey` is well-suited to accomplish. If my answer is followed, no further database/model change is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
{% for product_image in product.images.all %}
    <img src="{{ product_image.image.url }}" alt="{{ product_image.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

in place of the commented-out `<img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="">`. The key here is the use of `product.images.all`. I recommend you read about the Django ORM's [reverse relations feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: tried before and now. display nothing. :(. Thank's for sugestion

Comment: @nick.cmn sorry, I just saw that you used a `related_name` attribute in your `ForeignKey`. Can you try using `product.images.all` instead of `product.productimage_set.all`?